# Starting X gets stuck when ~/.xsession exists

Tags: x11, xinit

I have a single-board computer (Libre Computer Le Potato) that I'm trying to use to run a wall display. I want it to automatically launch X after it boots, and start Firefox.

Currently, I can get as far as starting the X server. My understanding is that now I need to make a ~/.xsession file to run Firefox, but when I do, the computer gets stuck in a loop.

The the .xsession file I'm using is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

# invoke global X session script
echo hey
. /etc/X11/Xsession

echo heyo
exec ~/autorun.sh
```

Where autorun.sh just contains the command to start Firefox. The .xsession-errors file that is produced is made up of blocks like this:

```
Xsession: X session started for kiosk at Sat Feb 24 20:46:13 UTC 2024
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1002/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/kiosk/.Xauthority
localuser:kiosk being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
hey
```

There are about four of those blocks per second.

When there's no local .xsession file, x starts without issue. What's going on here?

Comment: Do you really need to *"invoke global X session script"* here? I suspect that `/etc/X11/Xsession` is itself sourcing your user .xsession (either directly, or via a file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`) - leading to a loop condition

Comment: It looks like your local `.xsession` gets to the point of sourcing the global `/etc/X11/Xsession` but never returns from there. Look for anything including the command `exit` in the global `Xsession` file - you might be running into one of the sanity checks within. The suspicion of @steeldriver is also a strong possibility.

Comment: @steeldriver, your assessment was 100% right. The global is supposed to call the local, not the other way around. I found that line somewhere online and didn't question it. If you make that into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!